# Having troubles moving heavy CPU tasks in workers inside Electronjs

Tags: electron

I'm new to electron and i'm trying to understand how to deal with heavy tasks and prevent blocking the renderer process. I made an app that illustrate a minimal version of my actual use case. If anyone is able to share some feedback. I couldn't find a lot of stuff or example of app dealing with heavy stuff in workers.

The purpose of this eletronjs is to learn how to handle heavy tasks. From the doc, it says that heavy stuff shouldn't be run in the main process to prevent blocking the UI. In fact, in my use case, i need to save images and compare them to find differences and it actually freeze the UI.

In this minimalist app, I try to capture a screen of a browser, save it as a file and then try to compare it using Jimp. To do so, I created a worker named screen-and-capture responsible of doing the heavy stuff. In the main process, i'm spawning an utility process that execute the worker.

```js
// src/worker/capture-and-diff/index.ts (Worker for heavy operation)

import { desktopCapturer } from 'electron';
import Jimp from 'jimp';
import path from 'path';
import sharp from 'sharp';

export async function captureScreen() {
  // Issue 1 : DesktopCapturer is not accesible
  const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window'],
    thumbnailSize: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
    },
  });
  const browser = sources.find((s) => s.name === 'Chrome');

  if (browser == null) {
    return console.debug('Unable to find browser. Is it running?');
  }

  await sharp(browser.thumbnail.toPNG())
    .jpeg({ quality: 100 })
    .resize({
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      position: 'bottom',
    })
    .toFile(`generated/compare.jpeg`);
  const [base, compare] = await Promise.all([
    Jimp.read(path.join(__dirname, `../../../../assets/base.png`)),
    Jimp.read(`generated/compare.jpeg`),
  ]);

  // Issue 2 : This is heavy, that's why we want to run it in a child process
  const diff = Jimp.diff(base, compare, 0.1);

  return diff;
}
```

```js
// src/main.ts (Electron Main process)

const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannelMain();
const utility_checkState = utilityProcess.fork(
  path.join(__dirname, '..', 'workers', 'capture-and-diff', 'dist', 'index.js'),
);
utility_checkState.stdout?.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`Received chunk ${data}`);
});
```

```json
// src/workers/screen-and-diff/tsconfig.json (ESlint to compile the .js for the utility process)

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

**Issues**

- Desktop Capturer is undefined in the utility process, why ?
- I had to create a second tsconfig file in the worker folder and handle the compilation separatly in order to use typescript and deliver a .js file for the main process, is it the right way to do so ?

**Repo**

You can find the full code here : https://github.com/imsamdez/electron-heavy-task-example

Thanks for your time & help!

Comment: Please share the relevant code in the question directly.

Comment: Sure, here we go!